# Reclick image to shrink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of images that expand when click but I would like for them to return back to their original size on re-click. I gave the images an initial class (.images) and then added a class "selected".

HTML:

```
<div class='images'>
    <img src="file:///F|/Desktop/testing new site/sdfs/img/work/Yama/yama1.jpg" width="200" height="150" />
    <img src="file:///F|/Desktop/testing new site/sdfs/img/work/Yama/yama2.jpg" width="200" height="150" />
    <img src="file:///F|/Desktop/testing new site/sdfs/img/work/Yama/yama3.jpg" width="200" height="150" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".images img").click(function () {
    $(".images img").removeClass('images')
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).animate({
        width: '50%',
        height: '50%'
    }, 50).css('z-index', 999);
});
```

So right now the images will expand correctly. I was thinking to just remove the added selected class so that it goes back to the default .images images with

```
  $(".images img").removeClass('active');
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I'm still very new to this so hopefully this explanation is detailed enough. Thanks!

Comment: Use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass`. If there are even more properties to change (for example, your `.animate`), you will have to set a flag and keep track which state the image is in. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/92gHX/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 options:

1. keep a flag or check the current class to know the image is grown or shrunk. then run your animation accordingly.
2. Use a class which would change the size. then `toggleClass` on click to grow or shrink on alternate clicks.
   To show animation, you could define a `transition` css property. So, whenever your class is toggled, the width property will not change abruptly but show an animation effect.

javascript for the 2nd option.

```
$("img").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

[See this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/32ZXK/).

Comment: Cool. Got it to work with that toggleClass. Do you have an example of a flag? I just googled it and it seems to be case specific?  *NVM got it*

Comment: you could use jquery data api to store the grown boolean flag. http://api.jquery.com/data/ . hasClass to check if the class is set or not also would work the same way as posted by @devric.

Answer (score 0):

if you can do css transitions, than all you need is just

```
.click(function() {  
      $(this).toggleClass('active) 
})
```

if you want to stick with jquery to animate

```
$(img).click(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('active') {
         // shrink it
         // remove clas
    } else {
         // expand it
         // add class
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

how about that. use animation method and event delegation

```
// n
$(".images").on('click','img',function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    $self.toggleClass('selected');

    var width = ($self.hasClass('selected')) ? $self.width() * 2 : $self.width() /2 ;
    var height = ($self.hasClass('selected')) ? $self.height() * 2 : $self.height() /2 ; 

    $self.animate ({ 
        width :  width+'px' , 
        height :  height+'px' 
    },  50 );
});
```

other